# How to deal with $x^T(A^TA+B^TB)x$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratics

I want to minimize $$\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \|Cx-d\|_2^2 + \|x\|_1$$

I know we can introduce an auxiliary variable and use ADMM to separate the $\ell_2$ and $\ell_1$ norms.

But is there a more convenient way, such as direcly combine $\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \|Cx-b\|_2^2$ into one $\ell_2$ norm? Just like we can transform numeral problem such as minimizing $(ax+b)^2+(cx+d)^2$ to minimizing $(ex+f)^2$.

I tried this way.
But I found that it's hard to deal with $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)+(Cx-d)^T(Cx-d)$. The core is that I don't know how to transform $x^T(A^TA+C^TC)x$ to $x^T(E^TE)x$. Maybe this method is called completing the squares?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “deal with” exactly—your idea looks good. The matrix $A^\text{T}A+B^\text{T}B$ is guaranteed to be positive semi-definite, so your optimization problem is still convex, _etc._

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't totally understand what you mean by "a convex problem as stated". I understand it's a convex problem, but only a problem in the format of $\ell_2+\ell_1$ (Lasso) has a numeral solution by soft thresholding, right? I want to find an easier way to solve the problem stated above so I considered find an "E" to transform $\ell_2+\ell_2+\ell_1$ to a Lasso problem. :)

Comment: And do you have any suggestion to help me make the title of this question more readable to others? Maybe someone else will have the same problem in the future, you know :)

Comment: The two terms $\| Ax - b \|_{2}^{2}$ and $\| Cx-d \|_{2}^{2}$ can easily be combined into a single term $\| Gx - h \|_{2}^{2}$ where $G$ just has the $A$ matrix stacked above the $C$ matrix and $h$ has the $b$ vector stacked above the $d$ vector.

Comment: Tangential comment, but instead of ADMM, another option is to use the proximal gradient method or an accelerated proximal gradient method (such as FISTA). This would avoid the need to solve a linear system of equations at each iteration, if that is desirable. The proximal gradient method and FISTA also have line search procedures available, so that you would not need to tune the step size.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, littleO. I once used FISTA to solve the problem of $\ell_2+\ell_1$ :) I forget that it can be used to solve these general problems. But it's still a method with iteration.